# php selecting from mysql and receiving th data types

Tags: php, mysql, database, variables, types

When selecting from a MySQL table in PHP the results are always strings. Is there a way to get the correct datatype already?

Consider my table:

```
 CREATE TABLE bar(
     id    INT,
     price FLOAT,
     name  VARCHAR(40));
```

Now what i have to do is:

```
   $result = mysql_query("SELECT id,price,name FROM bar");
   while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
   { 
      $row['id'] = (int)$row['id'];
      $row['price'] = (double)$row['price'];
   }
   mysql_free_result($result);
```

Is there a way to get the data-types correctly from the query transparently?

10x,
Aviv

Comment: Why do you need this actually? php is a language with weak dynamic typization. That is why we love it (yes, we do ;-). Don't try to change it. If you need some language with strong dynamic typization (that is what you're trying to get) you could try python.

Comment: I love PHP too, but some times, like in this case, i return it as JSON and in JavaScript i need it as number or string for the sorting mechanism.

Comment: I have to agree, the weak typing in PHP can really be more trouble than it's worth some times,  and ofrcing the data to be of a specific type can work around most of the issues that the weak typing can lead to.  see my question on switch statements to see just what can go wrong.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098104/odd-behaviour-in-a-switch-statement

Comment: I had the same question. The possible solution is with `$stmt->bind_result($var);` then `$var` will keep the Int datatype. See this: [PHP.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php#refsect1-mysqli-stmt.fetch-examples)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, all data that comes from mysql is a string actually and you cannot do anything with it.

Comment: Is this still the case in 2021?

Answer (score 0):

actually no, 
the only thing you can do is to check for datatypes,

pseudo:

```
if(is_int())
    (int)....
else if(is_float())
    (float)...
else ...
```

and check for all the types you are expecting... 
as a last resort it's always string.

but if you would use PDO you could get the dataTypes for the column and convert accordingly...

see: [List of PHP native_type's for PDO getColumnMeta()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1148797/list-of-php-native-types-for-pdo-getcolumnmeta)

Comment: String will always return `false` for `is_int()` and `is_float()`

Comment: ok you would have to use is_numeric first but the idea stays the same

Comment: `is_numeric()` will also always return `false` for string.

Comment: yes, my bad (+1 for catching me). But this solution is still error affected, since it could be a **string** '42' stored in `varchar(2)`. And it should be treated as a string (at least that is what OP wants).

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer to the question, but rather a way (hack?) around the issue.

```
CREATE TABLE bar(
    int_id       INT,
    float_price  FLOAT,
    varchar_name VARCHAR(40)
);
```

Then, as you retrieve everything, loop through the column/key names and process them according to type (everything before the first underscore) and column name (everything after the first underscore).

Also, this requires you to edit the tables.. which could be problematic.