# php PDO fetch data's type isn't expected

Tags: php, pdo, fetch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PDO + MySQL always returns strings, but what about MsSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6017354/pdo-mysql-always-returns-strings-but-what-about-mssql)

```
$stmt = DB::$dbh->prepare('SELECT id,title FROM map_level where id = ?');
$stmt -> execute(array($level));
$result = $stmt->fetch();
var_dump($result);
```

the id's definition is clearly an integer in database. but in return's result,it's a string type.

```
array (
    'id' => '1',
    0 => '1'
)
```

it's pretty annoying,i don't want convert every string to int manually.

Comment: PDO will return always a string with the result of query from each field.

Comment: PDO always returns strings. But it is not a problem, actually...

Comment: Case in point, `<?= '1' + '5' ?>` returns `6`. http://ideone.com/D0ztN

Comment: why isn't it a problem.what's the solution?

Comment: What's the problem? How is this affecting you?

Comment: "it's pretty annoying" -- why?  "i don't want convert every string to int manually." - so don't, php will do that for you

Comment: Cause PHP is loosely typed language.

Comment: thants for @zerkms and Roman Newaza ,you mentioned me,you're right.