# In Postgres, using fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM). How do I get rid of the Double quotes?

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo, double-quotes

How do I fetch the data without double quotes?

Let me explain:
I am using a PostgreSQL database and PHP PDO to fetch data.

The data it returns is :

```
[["1358991300","70175.47"],["1359077700","70437.59"]...]
```

But what I need is:

```
[[1358991300,70175.47],[1359077700,70437.59]...]
```

basically all the data, without the double-quotes.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Isn't it the `json_encode`?

Comment: Please show the query producing this data, the PostgreSQL version, and the output of the same query in `psql`.

Comment: well the query is:SELECT date_part('epoch',t.time) as unixtime, t.energy_consumption FROM( SELECT time, energy_consumption, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY energy_consumption) AS rownum FROM consumption WHERE id = '001EC60018E22' ) AS t WHERE t.rownum % 1440 = 0;

Comment: I basically need a unix timestamp and the data(float), but I only select every 1440th entry. And the version is PostgreSQL 9.1.2. I then proceed to json_encode it and send it over to the client

Comment: Just as a note it is json_encoded but the quotes exists beforehand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<del>Postgres</del> PDO returns strings in PHP instead of expected data types.

Try converting types via:

```
$timestamp = intval($row[0]);
$energy = floatval($row[1]);
```

**UPDATE**

PDO has limited support for type conversion via bindColumn:

[PDO + MySQL always returns strings, but what about MsSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6017354/pdo-mysql-always-returns-strings-but-what-about-mssql)

http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindcolumn.php

I do not use Postgres, so can someone confirm?

**UPDATE 2**

Since you are json_encoding, try (PHP >= 5.3.3):

```
json_encode($result, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

To automatically cast numeric strings to numbers.

Comment: This seems to be true. Is there no better way to get the numeric values instead of strings? The data to be handled will most likely reach a couple million.

Comment: That's a limitation of most db drivers for PHP and PDO, especially since you need a decimal value back.  What are you doing with the data that requires them to be converted explicitly?

Comment: It is going to be graphed, or downloaded. But I think I just found a solution! I can remove the quotes using json_encode($data, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK). This does remove the quotes, I'm just not sure how efficient this is.