# PDO's getColumnMeta() flags and native_type

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm looking for a list of flags PDO's `getColumnMeta()` can return however I can't find it anywhere.

Is there a list of the flags that `PDOStatement::getColumnMeta()` can return somewhere? Same for native_type. Google seems pretty helpless in this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List of PHP native\_type's for PDO getColumnMeta()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1148797/list-of-php-native-types-for-pdo-getcolumnmeta)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is [buried inside the source](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_4/ext/pdo/php_pdo_driver.h#382), where the flags are referred to by informal names. It is important to note that this feature is implemented on a per-driver level, so the various flags available and their exact values ultimately depend on the driver.

The flag values for MySql are defined [here](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_4/ext/mysqlnd/mysqlnd_enum_n_def.h#271), and the code that determines which of those flags may be added is [here](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_4/ext/pdo_mysql/mysql_statement.c#pdo_mysql_stmt_col_meta).

For other drivers, you would need to look up [`pdo_stmt_methods`](http://lxr.php.net/s?refs=pdo_stmt_methods&project=PHP_5_4) for each driver and look up the implementation of its `DRIVER_get_stmt_column_meta` implementation. For example, the [implementation for Postgres](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_4/ext/pdo_pgsql/pgsql_statement.c#pgsql_stmt_get_column_meta) does not provide any flags at all (which is to be expected since searching for macros defining the flag values turns up nothing, in contrast to what happens for MySql).

Comment: This is absolutely great! That's exactly what I was looking for. I only need the MySQL version :) Thank you!

Comment: @sztanpet I didn't see your message before, however, please see these two links on GitHub: https://github.com/php-src/php/blob/0eb3c377d49a331282b943dba165b4b9df56fad2/ext/mysqlnd/mysqlnd_enum_n_def.h#L271 and https://github.com/php-src/php/blob/0eb3c377d49a331282b943dba165b4b9df56fad2/ext/pdo_mysql/mysql_statement.c#L826 . I'm not quite sure what the first link referred to though. Additionally, these links are for whatever is in master right now, whereas Jon's links were for php 5.4.

Comment: The links are broken.  For PHP8.2, the two MySQL links (middle paragraph) are: https://heap.space/xref/PHP-8.2/ext/mysqlnd/mysqlnd_enum_n_def.h?r=277e169e and https://heap.space/xref/PHP-8.2/ext/pdo_mysql/mysql_statement.c?r=aff36587#765, with the latter providing the strings I was looking for.